# Put two monadic values into a pair and return it

Tags: haskell, monads, parsec, applicative, pointfree

I am playing with Parsec and I want to combine two parsers into one with the result put in a pair, and then feed it another function to operate on the parse result to write something like this:

```
try (pFactor <&> (char '*' *> pTerm) `using` (*))
```

So I wrote this:

```
(<&>) :: (Monad m) => m a -> m b -> m (a, b)
pa <&> pb = do
  a <- pa
  b <- pb
  return (a, b)
```

And

```
using :: (Functor f) => f (a, b) -> (a -> b -> c) -> f c
p `using` f = (uncurry f) <$> p
```

Is there anything similar to (<&>) which has been implemented somewhere? Or could this be written pointfree? I tried `fmap (,)` but it seems hard to match the type.

Comment: Andy Gill calls this the `both` combinator in documentation on Chalkboard and Kansas-Lava. I haven't seen it defined anywhere, but I have defined it myself at least once.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there anything similar to (<&>) which has been implemented somewhere? Or could this be written pointfreely? I tried fmap (,) but it seems hard to match the type.

I don't now if it's implemented anywhere, but `<&>` should be the same as `liftM2 (,)`. The difference to `fmap` is, that `liftM2` lifts a *binary* function into the monad.

Comment: It's too bad that we can't make it infix:  ``foo `liftM2 (,)` bar``.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I want, though I ended up with `liftA2 (,)`

Answer (score 11):

Better than `<&>` or `liftM2` would be

```
(,) <$> a <*> b
```

since Applicative style seems to be gaining popularity and is very succinct. Using applicative style for things like this will eliminate the need for `<&>` itself, since it is much clearer than `(,) <$> a <*> b`.

Also this doesn't even require a monad - it will work for Applicatives too.

Comment: And you don't need `using`, either: you can just use `(*)` instead of `(,)` as in `(*) <$> a <*> b`.

Comment: Thank you, I ended up with `liftA2 (,)`. I still want `<&>` and `using` though, because I want to change the order of arguments. i.e. putting `(*)` on the end.

Answer (score 6):

Using applicative style, there is no need to put the intermediate results into a tuple just to immediately apply an uncurried function. Just apply the function "directly" using `<$>` and `<*>`.

```
try ((*) <$> pFactor <*> (char '*' *> pTerm))
```

In general, assuming sane instances of `Monad` and `Applicative`,

```
do x0 <- m0
   x1 <- m1
   ...
   return $ f x0 x1 ...
```

is equivalent to

```
f <$> m0 <*> m1 <*> ...
```

except that the latter form is more general and only requires an `Applicative` instance. (All monads *should* also be applicative functors, although the language does not enforce this).

Comment: Actually this is where I came from. :) But I want to put `(*)` on the end, thus introducing `<&>` and `using`. I ended up with `liftA2 (,)` though. Yeah, if Applicative could do the job, then why not?

Answer (score 3):

Note, that if you go the opposite direction from `Applicative` you'll see that the way you want to combine parsers fits nicely into [Arrow](http://www.haskell.org/arrows/) paradigm and [Arrow parsers](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Arrow#Parser) implementation.
E.g.:

```
import Control.Arrow

(<&>) = (&&&) 

p `using` f = p >>^ uncurry f
```

Comment: Interesting... it seems I need to rewrite the parsers to fit into this though?

Comment: Yes, Parsec is monadic not arrow parser (unlike `PArrows`). I am not sure how widely used arrow parser are (I suspect not very widely) though they are supposed to be more efficient (but probably harder for understanding as well).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could use applicative style but I don't believe that answers either of your questions.

Is there some already defined combinator that takes two arbitrary monads and sticks their value types in a pair and then sticks that pair in the context?

Not in any of the standard packages.

Can you do that last bit point free?

I'm not sure if there is a way to make a curried function with an arity greater than 1 point free. I don't think there is.

Hope that answers your questions.

Comment: The `((.) . (.))` combinator is often used to make a function with arity greater than 1 point free. But using auxiliary functions is even better!

Comment: Thank you for your direct answer. :) I don't understand why curried function with an arity greater than 1 can't be point free though. Isn't `(<&>) = liftA2 (,)` point free? Can you elaborate or give me some reference? Thanks!